# List shuttle selected value

Tags: jsf, richfaces

### Background

Using a JSF `listShuttle` component.

### Problem

Put the selected value of the second box to be in the other `outtext` box.

### Question

How do I put the value selected in the right-hand box of a list shuttle into an `outputText` field?

### Editor's Note

The following image is my interpretation of the original question:

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand the question. Can you provide more details and/or a screen shot of what you are trying to d?

Comment: If the image I have shown is not what you want, please change it accordingly. Pictures are easier to understand than written words sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

The second box (right side) is a list, if you want to display a particular value you would have to extract it from a list or do something like this:

```
#{bean.list[2]}
```